# How to integrate payu money payment gateway in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, payumoney

How to integrate Payu Money in rails 4.

I have not found any proper documentation.

I use this gem https://github.com/payu-india/payumoney-integration-kit-ror

but in this i got some error when i run 'rails s'.

**ERROR :**

```
/home/tps/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/active_merchant_payu_in-0.0.1/lib/active_merchant_payu_in.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_merchant/billing/integrations (LoadError)
```

Comment: Hi JIggs, did you get any solution?

Comment: No @RSB, i didn't get any solution yet.

Comment: @Jiggs As far as I know these gems are just wrappers for the apis..so better to work with their api's directly from scratch rather than fiddling around with an outdated gem with scarce documentation..